# Trouble converting python array to java array

Tags: java, python, arrays

I am in the process of converting a block of python code to java.  Code determines sun and moon rise and set times.
95% of the code conversion is fine but I am stuck on converting the python array **moonArray** to java as its not making sense.  Coding up the java version is a trival task and dont need help with that, just understanding what the python array is doing.

PYTHON CODE:

```
def riseSetString(self, dis, utcdis):
    moonArray = self.risesetlist(dis, utcdis)
    moonString = "moonrise time is " + moonArray[0]
    moonString += "\nmoonset time is " + moonArray[1]
    moonString += "\n{} iterations".format(moonArray[2])
    print(moonString)

def risesetlist(self, dis, utcdis):
    y = datetime.datetime.utcnow().year
    m = datetime.datetime.utcnow().month
    d = datetime.datetime.utcnow().day + dis
    h = datetime.datetime.utcnow().hour
    mins = datetime.datetime.utcnow().minute
    second = datetime.datetime.utcnow().second
    moonArray = self.calculate(y, m, d, h, mins, second)
    msd = moonArray[8]
    mra = moonArray[5]
    mdecl = moonArray[6]
    gmsto = moonArray[11]
    hmm = radians(-0.583) - msd
    numerator = (sin(hmm) - sin(radians(self.localLat)) * sin(mdecl))
    divisor = (cos(radians(self.localLat)) * cos(mdecl))
    mlha = numerator / divisor
    mlha = acos(mlha) * 12 * 15.0 / (15.04107 * pi)
    utcmoon = (degrees(mra) - gmsto * 15 - self.localLong) / 15
    a = mlha
    c = 1
    ff = 0
    while abs(c) > 0.000001:
        y = datetime.datetime.utcnow().year
        m = datetime.datetime.utcnow().month
        d = datetime.datetime.utcnow().day + dis
        h = utcmoon + a
        moonArray = self.calculate(y, m, d, h, 0, 0)
        msd = moonArray[8]
        mra = moonArray[5]
        mdecl = moonArray[6]
        gmsto = moonArray[11]
        hmm = radians(-0.583) - msd
        numerator = (sin(hmm) - sin(radians(self.localLat)) * sin(mdecl))
        divisor = (cos(radians(self.localLat)) * cos(mdecl))
        mlha = numerator / divisor
        mlha = acos(mlha) * 12 * 15.0 / (15.04107 * pi)
        utcmoon = (degrees(mra) - gmsto * 15 - self.localLong) / 15
        b = mlha
        c = abs(b - a)
        a = mlha
        ff += 1
        if ff >= 100:
            break

    moonset = mlha + utcmoon
    c = 1

    while abs(c) > 0.000001:
        y = datetime.datetime.utcnow().year
        m = datetime.datetime.utcnow().month
        d = datetime.datetime.utcnow().day + dis
        h = utcmoon - a
        moonArray = self.calculate(y, m, d, h, 0, 0)
        msd = moonArray[8]
        mra = moonArray[5]
        mdecl = moonArray[6]
        gmsto = moonArray[11]

        hmm = radians(-0.583) - msd
        numerator = (sin(hmm) - sin(radians(self.localLat)) * sin(mdecl))
        divisor = (cos(radians(self.localLat)) * cos(mdecl))
        mlha = numerator / divisor
        mlha = acos(mlha) * 12 * 15.0 / (15.04107 * pi)
        utcmoon = (degrees(mra) - gmsto * 15 - self.localLong) / 15
        b = mlha
        c = b - a
        a = mlha
        ff += 1
        if ff >= 200:
            break

    moonrise = utcmoon - mlha
    moonrise = timeadjust(moonrise, utcdis)
    moonrise2 = decimaltominsecs(moonrise)
    moonset = timeadjust(moonset, utcdis)
    moonset2 = decimaltominsecs(moonset)

    return ["{}:{}:{}".format(floor(moonrise),
                              moonrise2[0], moonrise2[1]),
            "{}:{}:{}".format(floor(moonset),
                              moonset2[0], moonset2[1]),
            ff, [moonrise, moonrise2, moonset, moonset2]]
```

In the risesetlist function moonArray is called as follows:

```
moonArray = self.calculate(y, m, d, h, mins, second)
```

and the within a while loop

```
moonArray = self.calculate(y, m, d, h, 0, 0)
```

So how then can variables be assigned from array locations [8],[6],[11] as in both array constructors only 0..5 exist?

```
msd = moonArray[8]
mra = moonArray[5]
mdecl = moonArray[6]
gmsto = moonArray[11]
```

So, I just need to know what the moonArray is doing in python so I can code up the java version.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Showing us the `self.calculate()` method would be helpful.  I assume Python can/is returning multiple values here, possibly an array slice of some sort.

Comment: That code is pretty hard to read due to direct array manipulations without any comments etc. Also the `calculate()` method is missing. I also suggest you ask a specific question instead of asking the rest of us to read the code.

Comment: thanks markspace, I did not see that as the calculate method returns 13 items in the array.

Comment: @Thihara, agreed.  I dont expect you to have to read the code but here it is for completeness.  I will take what markspace commented and keep figuring it out.  https://github.com/asdfhamiltonian/planets/blob/master/luna.py